# Environment Variable is not getting created in the Given Path

Tags: amazon-ec2, environment-variables, aws-cloudformation, user-data

I used the below mentioned Script in Userdata Section of the Cloudformation template to Set the Environment Variable but Environment Variable is not getting created and No content in setenv file

```
"echo 'export ec2userdata='variable > /root/setenv\n",
{
"Fn::Join" :
   ["",
      [ "echo 'export environment'=",
        {"Ref" : "EnvironUsed"},
          " >>/root/setenv\n"]]
 },
```

in the file /root/setenv the environment Variables has to be stored, Which will be later used by other scripts

Answer (score 1):

What you have explained is an expected behavior. This is because when you create environment variables using commands such as 'set'/'export'. Those variables are created surely but are active for that particular bash context.

Once another script is executed, they are not found because they were never the part of the new bash execution context.

Something that you can do here is store the data to some .txt file say as a key value pair. Your later scripts will be able to reference it for the values.

Hope it helps.